# Liferay Portlet development Ivy

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, ivy, liferay-ide

I'm trying to develop a portlet using JSF and Primefaces, When I create my project under eclipse kepler (using plugin sdk 6.1.1), I have a problem on portlet.xml :

> Could not resolve Portlet class
>   "javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet"

and when I try Ivy resolve  I have the following error :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPException
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)   at
>   org.apache.ivy.util.Configurator.addChild(Configurator.java:586)  at
>   org.apache.ivy.util.Configurator.startCreateChild(Configurator.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.inConfiguratorStarted(XmlSettingsParser.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.startElement(XmlSettingsParser.java:201)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:274)    at
>   org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.parse(XmlSettingsParser.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.load(IvySettings.java:391)
>     at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.configure(Ivy.java:416)   at
>   org.apache.ivyde.internal.eclipse.CachedIvy.getIvyFromFile(CachedIvy.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivyde.internal.eclipse.CachedIvy.doGetIvy(CachedIvy.java:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivyde.internal.eclipse.CachedIvy.getIvy(CachedIvy.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivyde.internal.eclipse.resolve.IvyResolveJob.doRun(IvyResolveJob.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.ivyde.internal.eclipse.resolve.IvyResolveJob.run(IvyResolveJob.java:85)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException cannot be found by
>   org.apache.ivy_2.3.0.final_20130110142753     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    ... 31 more

Can any one tell me please how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The following Maven Central search reports two matches. Include one of these jars in your classpath:

- [g:"org.bouncycastle" AND fc:"org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException" AND v:"1.50"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.bouncycastle%22%20AND%20fc%3a%22org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException%22%20AND%20v%3a%221.50%22)

Without more details difficult to tell why NoClassDefFoundError exception is being thrown.